# The Pom woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available by using jaxws-maven-plugin:1.11:wsimport

Tags: maven, jaxws-maven-plugin

I want to use  jaxws-maven-plugin to create the SEI. But there is a warning in the `mvn install` process. Under ....m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\wstx-asl\3.2.3, I could find the missing pom like the warning saids.

Part of my pom.xml

```
        <plugin> 
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>file:/XXXXXXX.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls> 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

After executed `mvn intall` I got the output like this:

```
[INFO]  
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.3/wstx-asl-3.2.3.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.3/wstx-asl-3.2.3.pom (2 KB at 4.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.3/wstx-asl-3.2.3.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.3/wstx-asl-3.2.3.jar (508 KB at 4062.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:1.11:wsimport (default) @ test ---
[WARNING] The POM for woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available
...
```

I have no idea, what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the missing maven dependency is causing the problem.
Define in your pom file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
   <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This should fix the warning.